# How to put key,value pair in dictionary in position based on sorted keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I look for something like [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) in C++. I know normal python dict dont support order. I found ordereddict in collections. But it do not work as expected.

```
>>> odict = OrderedDict()
>>> odict['z'] = '1'
>>> odict['a'] = '2'
>>> odict['y'] = '3'
>>> print(odict)
OrderedDict([('z', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('y', '3')])
```

But I would like to have order, like this:

```
OrderedDict([('a', '2'), ('y', '3'), ('z', '1')])
```

Comment: Ordered dict remembers the order in the way they are updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collections.OrderedDict` remembers item *insertion* order.  You're looking for something like a [sorteddict](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sorteddict.html) which is part of the [blist third party package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/)...

The alternative is to sort the keys *before* you pack them into the `OrderedDict`, but things will likely become un-sorted if you need to add more items ...

Answer (score 1):

Ordered dict remembers the order in the way they are updated 
you can use sorted to sort:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 4}
>>> [x for x in sorted(a.items(),key=lambda x:x[0])]  # sorted on keys
[('a', 1), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]
```

if you want to sort on values:

```
>>> [x for x in sorted(a.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])]
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reorder an ordered dict, the order is determined when the data is added. But you can make a new one based on the original:

```
odict = OrderedDict([('z', 1), ('a', 2), ('y', 3)])
odict_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(odict.iteritems()))

# gives OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('y', 3), ('z', 1)])
```